# google + ajax / _escaped_fragment_

Tags: ajax

does anyone know what happens if I have a **script?_escaped_fragment_=a** that returns a link to **#!b** (so it will become **script?_escaped_fragment_=a#!b**)?

will google try to access **script?_escaped_fragment_=b**?

Comment: the way google crawler deals with AJAX content: http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/getting-started.html

Comment: Have you found a way to work arround this issue? Is the solution to  absolute Links everywhere? We are facing the same challenge.

Answer (score 1):

No - Googlbot will not crawl that link. According to the Google specification, Googlebot will not crawl a URL on your site that contains _escaped_fragment_ .

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct solution is to work with the base tag:

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp

With the correct base tag even relative links do not contain "_escaped_fragment_" so they should be indexed by google.

Answer (score 0):

I do it like this:

```
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_escaped_fragment_=(.*)$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/snapshots/views/ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ /snapshots/views/%1 [L]
```